# Execute batch script from powershell with feedback

Tags: powershell

I need your valuable comments/advice on how we could implement powershell script to send feedback to users during its execution based on its runtime.

Powershell script will be executing a batch script.

```
Clear-Host
cmd.exe "/c G:\BEKDocs\Batch\Batch1.cmd" 
Write-Host "The Exit code from Batch1 is " $LastExitCode
```

Batch script will do some processing on its own, i want the power shell script to provide the feedback to few set of users on the below occasions through mail communication using SMTP (I have SMTP configured in the server).

1. When the script starts (Mail should be sent).
2. If the script completes within a minute.
3. If the script runs for more than a hour.
4. If the script fails.

Regards,
Naga

Comment: For sending mail, look at the help page on the Send-MailMessage command.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Send-MailMessage`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849925.aspx) to send mail. Use [`Measure-Command`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849910.aspx) to measure the execution time of a command. Use `$LASTEXITCODE` to determine whether an external command succeeded or failed.

```psh
$from = 'sender@example.com'
$to   = 'recipient@example.com'

Send-MailMessage -From $from -To $to -Subject 'script started'

$time = Measure-Command { & cmd.exe /c "G:\BEKDocs\Batch\Batch1.cmd" }

if ( $time.TotalMinutes -le 1 ) {
  Send-MailMessage -From $from -To $to -Subject 'script completed within 1 min'
} elseif ( $time.TotalMinutes -gt 60 ) {
  Send-MailMessage -From $from -To $to -Subject 'script ran longer than 1 hour'
}

if ( $LASTEXITCODE -ne 0 ) {
  Send-MailMessage -From $from -To $to -Subject 'script failed'
}
```